# Convert List<int> from bluetooth characteristics into double - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to process the characteristic data received from an Arduino Nano33BLE device.

Flutter reads in a List such as:
`value = [165, 8, 0, 0]`

This needs to correspond to the double: **2213**

I cannot figure out how to convert this. So far the following has failed:

`print(new String.fromCharCodes(value));`

I cannot find anything in the Arduino bluetooth docs to explain the nature of the List and how to convert back to the initial double after it has been read by flutter  though: `_characteristic.value.listen((value) {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution!

```
import 'package:convert/convert.dart';

List<int> reversed = new List.from(value.reversed);
String hexValue = hex.encode(reversed);
print(int.parse(hexValue, radix: 16));
```